# TypeORM - left joining without "deletedAt IS NULL"

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

Been searching this one for a while now, not sure if this is something unorthodox in the SQL world but I am trying to do a left join that counts with not null "deletedAt" column, but I cannot seem to find a way to do a left join which includes deletes.

This is just a dummy example that illustrates what I am trying to do, in this case I want to retrieve the person's information as well as the job's, but the job has been soft-deleted.

```
this.createQueryBuilder('person')
  .leftJoinAndSelect('person.job', 'job')
```

The SQL query produced by this implicitly adds "IS NOT NULL" on the **left join** but I have this scenario in which I need the information from a record that is indeed deleted.

I haven't been able to find a way to include this as you would do it at the root level by including.

```
.withDeleted();
```

Anyone has any tips?

Comment: Try using the .getRaw methods or this.repository.manager.createQueryBuilder() with the second method you have to specify the from clause and the selected fields.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In my tests, TypeOrm generates a different query depending on whether `.withDeleted()` is before or after `.leftJoinAndSelect()`

```
// Normal case: Exclude both soft-deleted 'Person' and 'Job':
        this.createQueryBuilder("Person")
        .leftJoinAndSelect('Person.job', 'Job');

// 'withDeleted() after the join: Include soft-deleted 'Person' BUT EXCLUDE soft-deleted 'Job':
        this.createQueryBuilder("Person")
        .leftJoinAndSelect('Person.job', 'Job')
        .withDeleted();

// 'withDeleted() before the join: Include both soft-deleted 'Person' and 'Job':
        this.createQueryBuilder("Person")
        .withDeleted()
        .leftJoinAndSelect('Person.job', 'Job');
```

So if you want to exclude the soft-deleted 'Person' but include the soft-deleted 'Job' (what I would expect), you can use withDeleted before the join (which will include everything) and add your own condition to then exclude soft-deleted 'Person' (i.e. add condition `"Person.deletedAt IS NULL"`). This way you don't need to do a complete RAW query:

```
// 'withDeleted() before the join with extra condition: Exclude soft-deleted 'Person' BUT INCLUDE soft-deleted 'Job':
        this.createQueryBuilder("Person")
        .withDeleted()
        .andWhere("Person.deletedAt Is Null")
        .leftJoinAndSelect('Person.job', 'Job');
```

(I tested with both TypeORM 0.2.30 and 0.2.31 and saw the same behaviour).

Comment: Hello there @Edward, thanks for the reply. I am using TypeORM 0.2.31 which appears to be the version of that thread you've linked!

As per the logging, which I was luckily already using, the query always prints ' AND "job"."deletedAt" IS NULL'.

I am querying using getMany:
this.createQueryBuilder('person').leftJoinAndSelect('person.job', 'job').getMany();

I am using postgres.

I've noticed the change https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/commit/d7cb338145f2c3e009c4934a2aa882df74bc7dc8#diff-52bea788267888fdbb5f795f0dfb61504f16bd43e0afdfa28848abb4435121b5R1339 could it be metadata?

Comment: Hello again @FPJ: I was completely wrong: It DOES add' AND "job"."deletedAt" IS NULL' , as you said. It seems bad behaviour to me, not what I expected, and I missed it when I tested - I guess I saw what I wanted to see! Same behaviour for both TypeORM 0.2.30 and 0.2.31. I'm going to edit my answer to suggest a workaround.

Comment: Hey again @Edward. Completely fine, the behaviour appears to be something new if I am not mistaken. This workaround unfortunately does not work. The withDeleted is applied to "Person" and I actually wanted it to be added to "Job". The only work around I've found so far is to make a RAW query (since my actual query is pretty big), which defeats completely the purpose of TypeORM :( I just don't understand why I can't find an option to simply shut down the implicit condition applied by the left join...

Comment: Hi again @FPJ : I changed my answer again - The generated query seems to depend on where you place .withDeleted(). I hope you use my final idea to make it work for you.

Comment: I believe I missed my tests with the withDeleted positioning. I've resorted to reverting back to 0.2.30 since I am close to a release and wanted everything stable, but I do whole heartedly appreciate your explanation as I'll be taking this to my next update. Not sure of why such a big change on their end but I'm sure it'll make sense. Big thank you for the effort, you've been quite helpful!